# Stripe PHP payment intent catch errors

Tags: php, stripe-payments, guzzle

Trying to catch the errors when creating a payment intent using stripe but im getting weird Guzzle errors. Below is the code:

```
try {
  $intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create($payload);
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  print( json_encode($intent->jsonSerialize() ));
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
  // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
  http_response_code(429);
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
  // Card was declined
  logAlert("Card was declined {$e->getError()->message}");
  http_response_code(402);
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
  http_response_code(400);
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
  http_response_code(503);
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  http_response_code(511);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  error_log("ERROR: {$e->getMessage()}");
  http_response_code(500);
}
```

I know the payload, stripe configs, etc are correct because cards are passing. Its only when i use a declining card that it errors out to a 500 without being caught by the catch blocks. Below is the error im getting:

12-Jul-2023 12:41:51 America/Edmonton] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 3:  (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:201

/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(105): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError()

Any help would be appreciated, pulling my hair out trying to figure out why nothing is hitting the exception catchers. Not even the last catch all for all exceptions.

Comment: Place the call to `paymentIntents->create()` inside the `try` block

Comment: Woops sorry i was reformatting this for stack overflow, it was inside the try catch block i just pasted it wrong. I have edited the question